# Jenkins, Job killed, Workspace locked

Tags: java, jenkins, workspace

I'm facing the below issue..
Suppose you run a Jenkins job, this for some reason is killed by Jenkins, it could be for a timeout issue, or something like this...

```
Build timed out (after 40 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.
Build was aborted
```

The problem is that during the next run of the same job, it fails due to:

```
ERROR: Cannot delete workspace: remote file operation failed: C:/Jenkins   /workspace/... at hudson.remoting.Channel@430a642f:WIN-CI: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Jenkins\workspace\....cucumber-html-report\report.js: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Any Idea? It seems an issue of easy resolution, but it is not, because, it seems that the only way to delete the workspace, is stop the agent delete the worspace and restart the agent, this sounds a little bit in contrast with a solution that can be ran from jenkins, i mean, if the condition to delete the workspace is stop the agent, this cant be managed remotly...

I think is something really common, so i'll wait for your great suggestion! :)

Comment: Maybe it's worth to check which process locks the file `...\report.js` after the build is aborted in Jenkins.

Comment: Already known, its a cucumber  plugin running a googlechrome driver, this last locks the directory, nut unfortunately the plugin team cannot effort to fix it... Sounds same story of always :)

Comment: How long does your build take normally? If it's close to 40 min, maybe an increase of the build timeout would prevent this situation. If it's normally much shorter than 40 min. I don't know if there is a way to kill the cucumber plugin from remote.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use Sysinternals [handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) in your [pre-SCM build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) to unlock `report.js`.

A similar failure often occurred in our environment when the Jenkins Gerrit plugin would abort builds while it was in the middle of running `git-checkout` when a new patchset was pushed to a corresponding Gerrit change ([JENKINS-12513](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12513)).

To workaround the issue, we added a [pre-SCM build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) that called a Python script that used [handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) to report all open handles to `index.lock` in the workspace, close them, and then delete the lock file(s). This was safe to do because our jobs have their own workspace and no concurrency.